# Why can't I run my C# program in release mode?

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-mobile

I have sample code (for deal with scanner in Motorola HC700)

the problem is that i can run this program only on Debug mode

if I try to run on Release mode, I get this error:

The type or namespace name 'Mot' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the section of code where 'Mot' is used?

Comment: Have you made sure that required DLL files are copied to the output Release folder?

Comment: That's not a runtime error, that's a build error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a standard csproj, note that files and references can be conditional - i.e. only there in some configurations. You have to go out of your way to do this (the VS IDE doesn't let you do it - only via direct file edit), so it seems unlikely, but it is a *possibility*.

It is, unfortunately, quite hard to investigate without some concrete examples.

Answer (score 2):

Things you can to to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Search you code for #if directives and Conditional attribute. Sometimes they are used to disable part of the code in a DEBUG/RELEASE configurations. This could be the case.
2. Look for compiler warnings in the error list as well (i.e.: assembly not found and this may break your code later). Some library may be missing from your release build due to the script/build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Thompson's comment worked as an answer for me at least. Similar problem happened with. On toggling the  solution configurations from debug to release, an external dll reference would be lost. I copy pasted the dlls their from debug folder to release folder and came back to VS, selected release and hit F6 to debug and it was OK.

Using VS 2010 DotNet framework: 4